# Do not understand results returned by NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I evaluated

```
NSolve[
  (-130.0 Sin[5.0 t] + 61.0 Sin[10.0 t]) /
    (2.0 Sqrt[176.0 + 26.0 Cos[5.0 t] - 6.1 Cos[10.0 t]]) == 0.0, 
  t, Reals]
```

and got this as output:

```
{{t -> ConditionalExpression[12.5664 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t ->ConditionalExpression[1. (-2.51327 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (-1.88496 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (-1.25664 + 6.28319 C[1]),  C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (-0.628319 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (0.628319 + 6.28319 C[1]),  C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (1.25664 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (1.88496 + 6.28319 C[1]),  C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[1. (2.51327 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[-3.14159 + 12.5664 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[3.14159 + 12.5664 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
 {t -> ConditionalExpression[6.28319 + 12.5664 C[1],  C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
```

However, when I run the command without the numerator, I receive the roots I expect. I have also tried multiplying by the denominator raised to the -1 power and receive the same output as when it is in fraction form. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The solutions seem to be correct.  Why do you call them "junk errors"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issued raised is not really a problem; it arises from the OP not understanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

If you use exact input the equation can be solved exactly

```
eqn = (-130 Sin[5 t] + 
       61 Sin[10 t])/(2 Sqrt[176 + 26 Cos[5 t] - 61/10 Cos[10 t]]) == 0 // 
   Simplify;

sol = Solve[eqn, t, Reals] // Simplify
```

[image]

Since the function is periodic the solutions are also. The arbitrary integer constant `C[1]` is used to reflect the periodic solutions.

Verifying that each of these solutions satisfy the equation

```
Assuming[Element[C[1], Integers], eqn /. sol // Simplify]

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are as you obtained with [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
sol // N
```

[image]

To visually verify the results

```
pts = Table[{t, 0} /. sol /. C[1] -> c, {c, -2, 2}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;

Plot[Evaluate@eqn[[1]], {t, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Looking at the first few values of `C[1]`

```
t /. sol /. C[1] -> Range[-1, 1] // Flatten // SortBy[#, N] &

(* {-5 π, -4 π, -3 π, -((14 π)/5), -((13 π)/5), -((12 π)/
  5), -((11 π)/5), -2 π, -((9 π)/5), -((8 π)/5), -((7 π)/
  5), -((6 π)/5), -π, -((4 π)/5), -((3 π)/5), -((2 π)/
  5), -(π/5), 0, π/5, (2 π)/5, (3 π)/5, (4 π)/5, π, (
 6 π)/5, (7 π)/5, (8 π)/5, (9 π)/5, 2 π, (11 π)/5, (
 12 π)/5, (13 π)/5, (14 π)/5, 3 π, 4 π, 5 π, 6 π} *)

Differences@%

(* {π, π, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, \
π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, \
π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, \
π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π/5, π, π, \
π} *)
```

The solution covers all multiples of `π/5`. Consequently the solution can be simplified to

```
sol2 = {t -> ConditionalExpression[C[1]*π/5, Element[C[1], Integers]]};
```

Verifying,

```
Assuming[Element[C[1], Integers], eqn /. sol2 // Simplify]

(* True *)
```